# Pandas creating a perfect panel data, appending empty rows based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I am looking for a way to append empty rows to a dataframe if two conditions are met. The conditions are that if the index ID is not found in a specific year the code would add an empty row that has the index 'ID' and year but other columns are empty. The final purpose is to create a perfect panel data set where each observation is represented 7 times (based on year) although there might be data from some observations e.g. 1 time or 3 times (this is not constant but changes from time to time). These missing data rows would otherwise be empty except the index 'ID' and year.

Here is an example of what my dataframe all_data currently looks like:

```
ID      Year      Data1      Data2
345     2010        3          2
345     2011        1          4
345     2012        5          2
345     2013        3          1
345     2014        3          1
345     2015        3          1
345     2016        3          1
123     2010        1          1
123     2012        0          2
123     2016        0          2
```

Here is an example of what I am looking for.

```
ID      Year      Data1      Data2
345     2010        3          2
345     2011        1          4
345     2012        5          2
345     2013        3          1
345     2014        3          1
345     2015        3          1
345     2016        3          1
123     2010        1          1
123     2011                  
123     2012        0          2
123     2013
123     2014
123     2015
123     2016        0          2
```

I have over 200 observations and 20 Data columns so doing this manually takes too much time. This is what I have tried but it does not work. It returns the same dataframe and does not add any empty rows. The 'missing' is a list containing every unique ID that can be found from the all_data dataframe.

```
missing = ['345', '123']
sub_dfs = []
for year in [ 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 ]:
    sub_df = all_data.loc[ all_data[ 'Year' ] == year ].copy()
    if( year == 2010):
        sub_df.set_index( 'ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2011):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2012):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2013):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2014):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2015):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    if (year == 2016):
        sub_df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
        sub_df.reindex(sub_df.index.union(missing))
    sub_dfs.append(sub_df)

new_data = pd.concat(sub_dfs)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `Multiindex` created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) by all [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of `ID` with `np.arange` by minimal and maximal `year`s:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['ID'].unique(), 
                                  np.arange(df['Year'].min(), df['Year'].max() + 1)],
                                  names=['ID','Year'])

df =  df.set_index(['ID','Year']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)
     ID  Year  Data1  Data2
0   345  2010    3.0    2.0
1   345  2011    1.0    4.0
2   345  2012    5.0    2.0
3   345  2013    3.0    1.0
4   345  2014    3.0    1.0
5   345  2015    3.0    1.0
6   345  2016    3.0    1.0
7   123  2010    1.0    1.0
8   123  2011    NaN    NaN
9   123  2012    0.0    2.0
10  123  2013    NaN    NaN
11  123  2014    NaN    NaN
12  123  2015    NaN    NaN
13  123  2016    0.0    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

jezrael is always faster, but I'm trying to learn pandas here, so here's my attempt ;)

I'm using the resampling method: you want to fill in the blanks by resmapling the data to annual start ('AS') interval

First convert the 'Year' column to pandas datetime and set it as index

```
df.Year = pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format="%Y")
df = df.set_index('Year')
```

Then I process each unique ID seperatly and create a new output DataFrame

```
IDs = df.ID.unique()
newDf = pd.DataFrame()
```

The processing loop

```
for ID in IDs:
    # resample to annual start (although end would also be OK)
    temp = df[df.ID==ID].resample('AS').sum()
    # fill in the blanks, now 0, with the wanted data
    temp[temp.ID==0] = pd.DataFrame({'ID':ID, 'Data1':'', 'Data2':''},
        index=temp[temp.ID==0].index)
    # concat this new data with the output frame
    newDf = pd.concat([newDf, temp])
```

Finally clean up the output by removing the index and converting the datetime back to a string

```
newDf = newDf.reset_index()
newDf.Year = newDf.Year.dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Result:

```
    Year   ID Data1 Data2
0   2010  345     3     2
1   2011  345     1     4
2   2012  345     5     2
3   2013  345     3     1
4   2014  345     3     1
5   2015  345     3     1
6   2016  345     3     1
7   2010  123     1     1
8   2011  123            
9   2012  123     0     2
10  2013  123            
11  2014  123            
12  2015  123            
13  2016  123     0     2
```